# Setting up jQuery ajax converter for json parsing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, converters

I'm attempting to parse JSON response to convert ASP.NET dates to javascript dates.

The actual response looks like so:

```
{"Id":1,"Title":null,"Description":null,"Content":null,"PropagateModel":false,"Status":0,"ComponentPublishDate":"\/Date(1340299653555)\/"}
```

I extended the javascript string object to do the regex conversion from `\/Date(1340299653555)\/` to `new Date(1340298914781)`

```
String.prototype.parseWithJSONDate = function () {
   return this.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, 'new Date($1)');
};
```

Then i setup a <del>converter</del> filter to do the actual parsing.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
      dataFilter: function(data, dataType) {
        if (dataType === "json") {
          return data.parseWithJSONDate();
        }
        return data;
      }
    });
```

This converter doesn't work. The first issue i had with it was that the response would get corrupted somehow after the converter returns. I fixed that by calling `JSON.parse` like so `return JSON.parse(res)` at the end of function. Why in the world do i need to parse a string that's already a JSON string??

The second issue is that actual regex doesn't appear to be replacing values. The odd thing is i tested it outside of the function on a sample JSON string and it worked just fine.

Can anybody suggest anything? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
I think i figured out the answer to my first question. My converter was running for json and text data types. Which is likely the reason why i had to explicitly convert the return value to JSON. I removed text data type from the converter and updated the rest of the code accordingly.

**UPDATE 2**
I ended up creating a new view model where date is a formatted string. Not the best thing in world, but better than screwing around with jQuery ajax events.

Comment: Do you expect it to return a JSON String, or a JavaScript object.

Comment: Based on my understanding, the converter accepts a json string already. So, i'm assuming it should return a json string back. At least this is what i'm attempting to do.

Comment: By default, the `text json` converter returns a JavaScript object that represents the JSON string. If you simply want to change the json string before jQuery evaluates it, use a dataFilter.

Comment: Thanks. I just found the issue just before you responded and removed the text data type. I'm still not able to replace the date. Not sure if my regex is bombing somewhere or something else is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting all dates to appropriate format on the server and returning the value to client. Not the optimal solution, but i couldn't figure out how to convert with data filters.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `dataFilter` instead:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function(data,dataType) {
        if (dataType === "json") {
            return data.parseWithJSONDate();
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

This assumes that your `parseWithJSONDate` method returns a valid json string. You would then simply use `json` as your dataType.

The purpose of the dataFilter method is to sanitize the raw responsetext, which i think is perfect for this situation. As long as you return valid json, jquery will then parse that and turn it into a javascript object like normal.

Edit: it will probably fail now that i think about it, on the `new Date()` since that isn't valid json.

Comment: I did switch to data filter as you suggested. My converter wasn't even firing after i removed text data type from the declaration. The data filter still isn't converting the date. I'm not sure what you mean by new Date() not being valid JSON. I'm not trying to evaluate it, just simply fix the formatting and evaluate it at a later time when necessary.

Comment: If your dataType is `json`, jQuery will evaluate it regardless of you telling it to.